# Why I'm getting "Exception: Prelude.head: empty list"?

Tags: list, haskell, matrix, pattern-matching

Can't figure out why the pattern matching isn't working! I'm beginning with Hasklell, so be patient!

```
-- matrix implemented as a list of lists (rows of the matrix)
test_matrix3 = [[1,0,0],[2,-3,0],[4,5,6]]

-- transpose of a given matrix
transpose    (x:[]) = [x]
transpose all@(x:_) = map head all : transpose ([tail y | y <- all])
```

Executing:

```
*Main> transpose test_matrix3
[[1,2,4],[0,-3,5],[0,0,6],[*** Exception: Prelude.head: empty list
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This one worked for me:

```
transpose' ([]:_) = []
transpose' xs = (map head xs) : (transpose' (map tail xs))
```

Test:

```
*Main> transpose' test_matrix3
[[1,2,4],[0,-3,5],[0,0,6]]
```

Comment: Here the first clause is aware that the first element is an empty list, it assumes the rest elements are the empty lists, too. Second clause can be rewritten as just `transpose' xs = map head xs : (transpose' $ map tail xs)`.

Comment: I've just modify my example surrounding transpose recursive call with parentheses and **it's working**. I'm a little confused! **Why** this behavior? EDIT: wrong, works also without parentheses

Comment: The last call to `transpose'` is `transpose' [[],[],[]]`, it pattern-matches the first list, and ignores the rest list, which is `[[],[]]`.

Comment: @Gremo: How does your call with parens look like? I suspect you just mixed up your initial code from the question with some of its recent versions.

Answer (score 6):

```
  transpose [[1,0,0],[2,-3,0],[4,5,6]]
= [1,2,4] : transpose [[0,0],[-3,0],[5,6]]
= [1,2,4] : [0,-3,5] : transpose [[0],[0],[6]]
= [1,2,4] : [0,-3,5] : [0,0,0] : transpose [[],[],[]]
```

And here is where it happens.  This does not match the first pattern, because it is not a singleton list -- it is a list with three elements.  So:

```
= [1,2,3] : [0,-3,5] : [0,0,0] : map head [[],[],[]] : transpose (map tail [[],[],[]])
```

Which will give you one error for each empty list, since neither `head` nor `tail` are defined on empty lists.

Comment: Quite good explanation, but I can't understand why [[],[],[]] does not match the first one.

Comment: @Gremo: It would match, if there would be only one list `[[]]`, not three `[[],[],[]]`. Because `(x:[])` takes out the first element of a list and assumes there are no other elements, i. e. `(x:[])` is the same as `([x])`, but you have `(x:[[],[]])`, which is `[x,[],[]]`.

Answer (score 1):

Consider that you are working on a list-of-lists. Therefore your first pattern match always fails on your test matrix. Basically you keep taking the tail of every element of your list, but this doesn't reduce the number of elements in your list, it just reduces their individual size.

To correct this, you may want to modify your first pattern to match on the structure of `x`.

Remember, list-of-lists!

Comment: Sure I got it. But I can't find a good place to learn some kind "advanced" pattern matching. I tried ([]:_) and it's not working. Also ([],_) will only match [[],[]]...

Comment: @Gremo: `([],_)` is a tuple and therefore will only match a tuple, whose first element is an empty list. Try, for instance, to evaluate `let ([],_) = [[],[]] in 42`, you'll get a compile-time error in contrast to, for example, `let [[],_] = [[],[]] in 666`.