# Getting `head: empty list` error while trying to transpose a matrix

Tags: haskell, ghci

I wrote this program which is supposed to return the transposition of a matrix of integers.

```hs
trans:: [[Int]]-> [[Int]]
trans [[]]=[[]]
trans xss=[(transHead xss)] ++ trans(transTail xss)

transHead:: [[Int]]->[Int]
transHead []=[]
transHead [[a],[b]]=[a] ++ [b]
transHead xss= [head(head xss)] ++ transHead (tail xss)

transTail:: [[Int]]-> [[Int]]
transTail []=[]
transTail xss= [tail(head xss)] ++ transTail(tail xss)
```

The program compiles but it errors with "Main: Prelude.head: empty list"

Can you please help me to find a solution.

Comment: Is it a homework? Can you use Prelude functions?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why I'm getting "Exception: Prelude.head: empty list"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4883169/why-im-getting-exception-prelude-head-empty-list)

Answer (score 1):

It is usually *not* a good idea to work with `head` and `tail`: it is better to work with pattern matching here. Then the compiler can also show what patterns are not covered.

```
trans:: [[Int]] -> [[Int]]
trans [[]] = [[]]
trans xss = [transHead xss] ++ trans (transTail xss)

transHead:: [[Int]] -> [Int]
transHead [] = []
transHead [[a], [b]] = [a] ++ [b]
transHead ((x : _) : xss) = [x] ++ transHead xss

transTail:: [[Int]] -> [[Int]]
transTail [] = []
transTail ((_:xs):xss) = [xs] ++ transTail xss
```

If we compile this, we get the following compiler warnings:

```
<interactive>:7:1: warning: [-Wincomplete-patterns]
    Pattern match(es) are non-exhaustive
    In an equation for ‘transHead’: Patterns not matched: ([]:_)

<interactive>:12:1: warning: [-Wincomplete-patterns]
    Pattern match(es) are non-exhaustive
    In an equation for ‘transTail’: Patterns not matched: ([]:_)
```

Your `transHead` and `transTail` thus do not cover the case where the first item of the list of lists of items is empty.